# Issue with Date N Time in Java Selenium

Tags: java, selenium

please provide solution for this
I am trying to detect Date and time fields on CRM page form I have Written Code but it's giving Error I am getting error on Date and Time part. For date and time i have written Below code in POM. please find code with comments and screenshot of HTML

```
@FindBy(id="DateInput")
private WebElement date;
@FindBy(id="fmc_followupbyTimeInput")
private WebElement time;
public void updateForm() {
    date.clear(); // here I am able to clear date field
    date.sendKeys("12/24/2015"); // here I am able to set defined date passed as argument but oter 3 fields are getting disabled
    time.sendKeys("3:00 PM"); // on this line I am getting error as SourceNot found
}
```

please find screenshot of form and HTML

[image]

Comment: The component holding the time doesn't seem to be a component that accepts keys, like the text component holding the date. What is this "SourceNot found" error you're talking about? What exactly is the error?

Comment: @ThiagoPorciúncula error is like  a new tab is opening in eclipse named "Invoker.class" and getting text printed as  "Class file Editor.. Source not found... the jar C:\.selenium.jar has no source  attachement".

Comment: This... is not an error. This simply means Selenium's source is not attached to your workspace. Have you tried the code on my answer?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `time.sendKeys("3:00 PM");`, try this:

```
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.Select;

...

Select timeField = new Select(time);
timeField.selectByVisibleText("3:00 PM");
```

Comment: not running . got same message Selenium Source is not attached.
In HTML, Time code is not in Select TAG.. so should we go with Select Tag?
or we have any other approach